# Recursive way to find number of items in a object of array

Tags: javascript, recursion

What is the recursive way to get the number of titi in the following object :

```
{
    titi: "h0",
    history: [{
        titi: "h1",
        history: [{
            titi: "h11"
        }, {
            titi: "h12"
        }]
    }, {
        titi: "h12",
        history: [{
            titi: "h121"
        }, {
            titi: "h122"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Expected result is the total. In this example : 7.

Comment: I would suggest starting by writing out the steps you think you need to obtain an accurate count. What will be the precondition before each step and what inputs are you expecting at each step. Then write what the outcome of each step will be and the outputs. You may start iteratively first to see if you understand the problem completely. Then try a recursive method. Make certain you have an exit clause.

Comment: Uuuhhh... OP? You have comments and answers to your question...

Comment: @Jeremy : I did not responded to my answer ?!

Comment: What? No, it's just that for quite a long time, there were comments and answer to your question, and I thought you were just gone :)

Comment: @scrappedcola : my opinion is that it is a very basic algorithm exercice understandable just by looking at the json structure. I cannot just hack my mind to think recursively. And I cannot hack my mind for understanding people downvoting a question because they don't have the response.

Comment: @benek I did not downvote your question and my comment was a suggestion on how to "hack" your brain around a solution that is recursive. If you can't solve it via an iterative method then jumping to a recursive method is plain stupid. I very well could have handed you code but I neither code for free nor think it is helpful to you if you are to learn to actually code for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  titi: "h0",
  history: [{
    titi: "h1",
    history: [{
      titi: "h11"
    }, {
      titi: "h12"
    }]
  }, {
    titi: "h12",
    history: [{
      titi: "h121"
    }, {
      titi: "h122"
    }]
  }]
}

var numberOfTiti = 0;
function process (obj) {
  for (var index in obj) {
    if (index === 'titi') {
      numberOfTiti++;
    }
    if (typeof obj[index] === 'object') {
      process(obj[index]);
    }
  }
}

process(data);
console.log(numberOfTiti);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = {  titi:"h0", history : [{ titi :"h1", history : [{ titi :"h11"}, { titi : "h12"}] }, { titi : "h12", history : [{ titi :"h121"}, { titi : "h122"}]}]}

var count = 0;

function getCount(haystack, needle) {
    for (var k in haystack) {
        if (haystack.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
          if ( k == needle ) {count = count + 1};
          if (typeof haystack[k] === 'object') getCount(haystack[k], needle);
        }
    }
}

getCount(json, 'titi');
console.log('count: ',count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```
function countTiti(obj) {
  let count = 0;
  JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => { if (k === 'titi') count++; return v; });
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A funny, easy, and infinitely recursive way to do this :

```js
let obj = {
    titi: "h0",
    history: [{
        titi: "h1",
        history: [{
            titi: "h11"
        }, {
            titi: "h12"
        }]
    }, {
        titi: "h12",
        history: [{
            titi: "h121"
        }, {
            titi: "h122"
        }]
    }]
}

let count = JSON.stringify(obj).match(/"titi":/g).length

console.log(count) // 7
```

Comment: @torazaburo May I know why you modified my answer and added a key that's not in OP's question? And also, may I know why this has been downvoted? Cause it works, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, apparently not.